# What is difference between Spring Dispatcher Servlet and Web Deployment Descriptor?

Tags: spring, servlets, web.xml

Why do need to create a separate **Spring-servlet.xml**(Dispatcher Servlet) file in my Spring application? Why we can not keep all the request mapping in **web.xml**(Deployment Descriptor file)?

Answer (score 0):

J2EE specification drives what content has to be available inside web.xml. Web.xml provides URL to Servlet mapping where as Spring dispatcher servlet with help of its own configuration file provides mapping of request URL with controller class.